# Error when Trying to install aglio with npm

Tags: windows, bash, npm-install, windows-subsystem-for-linux, aglio

```
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/drafter/node_modules/protagonist/drafter/ext/sos/test/ext/Catch/projects/VS2008/TestCatch/TestCatch/TestCatch.vcproj'

npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.4.0+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "aglio"
npm ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/HEWLETT PACKARD'
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/drafter/node_modules/protagonist/drafter/ext/sos/test/ext/Catch/projects/VS2008/TestCatch/TestCatch/TestCatch.vcproj
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/drafter/node_modules/protagonist/drafter/ext/sos/test/ext/Catch/projects/VS2008/TestCatch/TestCatch/TestCatch.vcproj

npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /mnt/c/Users/HEWLETT PACKARD'/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am not sure about this problem. I have tried, but it is useless.
If the above error is not readable, you can see the link [here](https://pastebin.com/kLFyFxeG).

Reference to [agilo](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio).

Comment: I assume by "bash windows" you meant in the ternimal window, not on the Windows operating system, since you are tagging your question with the `ubuntu` tag. Am I right?

Comment: yes @TamerShlash . you'r right. this running on bash windows.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:
I used nvm and successfully installed aglio using node v0.12.

Discussed on the issue of github aglio
https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio/issues/175